# Getting $_POST fields before loading form php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to get all of the fields that will be submitted in $_POST, but before the page is loaded

```
$data['event'] = $_POSTKEYSFORFORM; //i don't care if they are empty
$this->load->view('event_v/form',$data);
```

In my template I have values set to `$event-key`, which causes an error obviously if the key does not exist.

Thanks!

Comment: is there not a hook point use can use?  
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html

Comment: isn't this already done as php runs line by line top to bottom ?

Comment: How do I get the keys of the form? It is just an html form embedded in the view. I have submitted anything to this controller method, the form is being loaded by the controller.

Comment: what are keys of form?

Comment: Haha well of course I know them, but that wouldn't be fun to type them all out, and say if the form is modified then I would have to appened/delete keys.

Comment: Tried http://www.php.net/isset ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know you cannot "grab the keys" of the POST before you send the POST request.
The controller has no way of knowing what's loaded in the view itself.

If it's **that** critical to you, You can pass the POST fields as an array to the view, have them echo out in the view, and so have perfect control(if they change, they change in one place only).

It's far from ideal as it's not dynamic to the amount of fields.
Other dirty hacks include having JS auto submit the form **once** and then collect the POST fields.

Why do you need the post fields without values though, Answering that question might make it easier for us to help out.